# Quickest way to clear non contiguous cells of contents using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 7 `worksheets` which I have clear before running another macro to update the sheets. I am using the code below but testing it with two worksheets it is slow! Is there a quicker way?

```
Sub clearplans()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("Plan")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Cpt Plan")
Set rng = ws.Range("F5:CN275")

    For Each c In rng
        If c.HasFormula = False Then
            c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Set rng = ws1.Range("F5:CN275")

    For Each c In rng
        If c.HasFormula = False Then
            c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mikku How do I change my code?

Comment: Your code is Clearing only the cells with Formula in it ? Is that what you want or the complete range ?

Comment: @Mikku I am clearing cells without formulas in.

Comment: Are columns consistent?  Either formula or no formula?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes columns are consistent.

Comment: Than can you just loop across the first row and clear one column at a time instead of cell-by-cell?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry do not understand.

Comment: @Anthony .. Try the `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents` as in the answer below to clear all the cells that doesn't have any formula in them at once without loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents` can solve your issue.**

**Try:**

```
Sub clearplans()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("Plan").Range("F5:CN275").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Cpt Plan").Range("F5:CN275").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've never tried this, but would this method work to parse all cells without formulas to a 2D array?

Comment: You can do that. Set the value equal to an array just as for a normal range. @TimStack

Comment: That could be very useful. Cheers